# Java DatagramPacket and DatagramSocket not receiving data

Tags: java

I am trying to receive a simple string using `DatagramPacket` and `DatagramSocket` class in Java.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String [] args){

    DatagramSocket aSocket = null;

    try{
        aSocket= new DatagramSocket();
        String aMessage = "my message";
        System.out.println("1");
        byte [] m = aMessage.getBytes();
        InetAddress aHost = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
        int serverPort = 6789;
        DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(m,aMessage.length(),aHost,serverPort);
        System.out.println("2");
        aSocket.send(request);
        System.out.println("3");
        byte [] buffer = new byte[1000];
        System.out.println("4");
        DatagramPacket reply = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);
        aSocket.receive(reply);
        System.out.println("5");
        System.out.println("DATA RECEIVED" + reply.getData());
        aSocket.close();

    }
    catch(SocketException ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch(IOException ioe){
       ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It's not printing the received data. I have put `System.out.println` just to see where the code is executed, and it stops at 4, it does not print 5, meaning the problem is just below 4. Why am I not receiving the data, can anybody help me with this please?

Comment: Is a reply being *sent?* By what code? Show us.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
       DatagramSocket aSocket = null;
try{
aSocket = new DatagramSocket(6789);
byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
while(true){
DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
aSocket.receive(request);
DatagramPacket reply = new DatagramPacket(request.getData(),
request.getLength(), request.getAddress(), request.getPort());
aSocket.send(reply);
}
}catch (SocketException e){System.out.println("Socket: " + e.getMessage());
}catch (IOException e) {System.out.println("IO: " + e.getMessage());}
    }
}

Comment: @arun sorry am new to this site, and i can't find how to add the code above, its working now, the error was in my network itself and i also made the changes to the datagramsocket as specified in the answer below. Thanks anyway, we are lucky to have people like you who are ready to help others :)

Answer (score 3):

@avi dont use the same datagram socket for getting rely. For getting reply you have to mention the port nomber of the server datagram socket.use

```
DatagramSocket datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket(6789);// Which is given by you only
```

then use  `datagramSocket.receive(reply);`

and also for getting address use this method

```
InetAddress aHost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
```

instead of

```
InetAddress aHost = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
```

Take a refrence of this link

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/UseDatagramSockettosendoutandreceiveDatagramPacket.htm

Comment: Thank you, its working fine now. Its so good to have people like you guys here, ready to help :)